# Programming TeXMaker: adding commands

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

I'd like to know whether there is a reference language for writing commands in TeXMaker (I'm using v 4.4.1 for MacOSX, btw).

My current problem is emulating the Emacs command `LaTeX-close-environment` but I was wondering whether there was a full TeXMaker command language reference.

Comment: Assuming you have TeXMaker 4.4.1 installed, you need to check the help user manual section 4.15 Extending the editor's functionality with scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TexMaker has a partial scripting language to extend the editors functionality. In essence you are using javascript (subset) to describe the desired editor actions to take effect at the location of the cursor.  It works well to create keyboard commands (e.g. shift-ctl-e) to modify a selected set of text.  There are minimum examples available of this feature being used.  And  frankly for the modification of text in a document, you are better off using LaTeX commands which can much more efficiently be modified and used as desired.

I am personally unaware of any scripts which exercise control outside of the editor environment. 
Section 4.15 in the user's manual provides limited guidance on the creation of scripts.  And, it assumes proficiency in javascript language (the qtscript dialect)

Comment: Mmm, yeah, section 4.15 give scant help on the subject. @R.Shumacher, LaTeX commands work on the text (i.e., affect the result not its typing) not on the editor usability. Not only XEmacs has a complete programming language, it comes with plenty of editor commands already built in.