# How to make TeXstudio recognize \DeclarePairedDelimiter declaration

Tags: texstudio, highlighting, auto-completion

I'm using TeXstudio as editor because I think it provides the best features among other software I tried (namely Kile and TeXworks), especially about highlighting, autocompletion and spell checking. It correctly recognizes all the commands and environments I use, even those I have declared myself in the preamble with `\newcommand`.

However I've got some lines like these

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norma}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

which TeXstudio doesn't recognize as valid commands and therefore highlights them in red throughout the text to mark them as bad LaTeX commands.

Anyway if I add them manually in the TeXstudio advanced highlighting option page and restart the program everything is fine and the bad red highlightings disappear.

However, is there a way to make TeXstudio aware of these new commands automatically or do I have to manually specify all of them in the options?

Edit: furthermore simply adding `\norma` as a new command in the options makes TeXstudio not aware that this is a new command that can be autocompleted: if I type `\norma` and then type `{` TeXstudio substitutes my typing with `\normalcolor{}`, which is not what I want!

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236559/17423

Comment: @SeanAllred That's Texmaker, not TeXStudio, they separated a long time ago.

Comment: See if the information in http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/665/ helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the help of @Torbjørn I came up with this workaround.

1. Create a `mydefinition.cwl` file and place it in the `%APPDATA%/texstudio` folder (I'm using Windows, don't know where it should go in other operative systems).
2. Add the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{cmd}{left_delim}{right_delim}#md` line in the `.cwl` file.
3. In TeXstudio Options -> Completion check the box of `mydefinition.cwl` that appeared in the list.

This fixed the problem for me: I get the correct autocompletion for my `\abs` and `\norma` commands!

Now a little explaination: as far as I could learn (but if anyone has further information please let me know!), the problem comes from TeXstudio `.cwl` files, which are not yet complete. There are some packages with some commands which haven't been added to the autocompletion files of TeXstudio yet. The TeXstudio team is working for improving this.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hacky workaround, but it is less tedious and it worked for me: make a \newcommand with the same name, but make sure LaTeX doesn't read it. To do this, place a line like

```
\iffalse
\newcommand{\abs}{abcdef}
\fi
```

in the preamble. The highlighting should work without affecting the document output. (Note: This does not however fix autocompletion.)